# Margin Bottom Not Working

Tags: html, css, margin

What is preventing margin bottom from working here?
http://jsfiddle.net/cq8VC/1/

I just want the active one to be jumping up in the air about 10px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, by adding a span around the internal elements of the list items as follows:

```
<div id="navigation"> 
    <ul id="links"> 
        <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
        <li><a class="active" href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></li> 
        <li><a href="whyme.html"><span>Why Me?</span></a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

And by changing your CSS to the following you should end up with the desired result:

```
#navigation ul#links li a.active{color:#1161A5; }
#navigation ul#links li a.active span { position: relative; top: -10px; }
#navigation ul#links li a{ font-family:LeagueGothicRegular;color:#ADC060;text-decoration:none;padding-left:10px;border-left:2px solid #1161A5;}
#navigation ul#links li a:hover,#navigation li:active{color:#1161A5;}
#navigation ul#links li:first-child a{border-left:none;}
#navigation ul#links li{float:left;font-size:1.5em;margin-left:10px;}
```

Comment: This works beautifully... Side note is there any way to decrease the size of the border?

Comment: @Maletor  on #navigation ul#links li a  its border-left:2px solid #1161A5; change it to border-left:1px solid #1161A5;

Comment: @sotiris... wouldn't that just change the width of the border? I think Maletor meant the height of it... correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could add display: block; height: whateverpx; into the #navigation ul#links li a declaration.  Not the most graceful way of managing it but it's all that immediately comes to mind.

Comment: @Hristo I think he just wish to change the border-width. The height is not set on css so it takes auto value from the browser. Maletor can correct me if I understood something wrong

Comment: @Sotiris. I agree with your way to change the width. If that is what Maletor wants, sweet :) To change the height, you can add a `height` property to `#navigation ul#links li` but I don't recommend that.

Comment: Ya I meant the height. Display block with height doesn't really do the tick, perhaps we need another span with a different class?

Comment: You can add another element before the `<a>` and give it a height and a left border, or you can surround the `<a>` with a `<div>` and give that a height and a left border... but that means you'd have to take off the left border in `#navigation ul#links li a`

Answer (score 2):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/vXaeP/1/

### CSS

```
#navigation ul#links li{
    padding-left:10px;
    border-left:2px solid #1161A5;
    float:left;
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#navigation ul#links li a{
    font-family:LeagueGothicRegular;
    color:#ADC060;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#navigation ul#links li a.active{
    color:#1161A5;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#navigation ul#links li a:hover {
    color:#1161A5;
}

#navigation ul#links li:first-child {
    border-left: 0px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="links">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="whyme.html">Why Me?</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use :

```
#navigation ul#links li a.active{color:#1161A5;position:relative;top:-10px;}
```

(since on inline elements)

Comment: Whilst that does the trick it moves the border-left up as well.

Comment: i don't think there's a way to get the text "higher" than its border anyway, is it?

Comment: Not within the same element it's not possible.  Adding the extra span element as per my expanded answer gets around that issue.

Comment: I'd like to know a way to move the text up without the border, but ya it does seem kind of impossible...

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine margin-bottom will not push the content up, but merely push everything else down.

Have you tried messing with positions? Try adding position: relative to the

and position: absolute to the  tag, but only the active link. Then you can reference it in CSS in a manner such as this.

li { position: relative; }
a:hover { position: absolute; top: -10px; }

I've not tested anything yet so don't hold me to it!! Ha!